# Which quests from the first Witcher games matter in the second?

Tags: the-witcher-series

I recently found out that I've lost my savegames from The Witcher. I decided, rather unwillingly, to replay the game in order to try and make the same decisions so that it'll be reflected correctly on the The Witcher 2 game.

However, I do not have enough time to replay it fully -- I want to go straight to the important quests, but of course I don't know which of those have impact on the second game.

That said, I'm not expecting a complete list of every quest available and whether or not it has any impact, but I wish to know which quests (other than the main, *necessary* quests) I have to do. Some examples (which I'll update as I remember):

- Does beating the Poker Dice quests change the game somehow?
- The weapon that you receive after collecting all Trophies gets carried over?
- The character build (talents) are reflected?

**Please, pretty please, do not write any spoilers!** I haven't played a single second of the game yet, and I love this game (enough the replay the old one just to get a working savegame).

Comment: From what I understand, you can bypass one mini-dungeon in the game if you sided with the Order of the Burning Rose at the end of the first game. (It happens pretty late, in Act 3, Iorveth's path)

Answer (score 9):

An imported Witcher 2 save retains several items (see below), roughly 1% of your accumulated Orens, there are a few minor dialogue changes and free goodies depending on choices you've made.

**Weapons retained:**

**Steel Swords**

- *Ard'aenye* - (only available to saves imported from the original version of *The Witcher*. This item was removed from the *Enhanced Edition*.)
- *D'Yaebl*
- *G'valchir*
- *Gwalhir*

**Silver Swords**

- *Aerondight*
- *Moon Blade*

Additionally, *Raven's Armor* will carry over to a new Witcher 2 game if imported from the first game.

As for plot choices carrying over, there are three notable ones in addition to path selection. Spoilers follow.

> If you saved **Thaler**, he will send you a letter when you get to Flotsam. This contains the *Dragon's Dream* formula. Additionally, whether you choose to kill or spare **Siegfried** (if neutral or siding with the Scoia'tel, see below for more details), and **Adda** affects some minor bits of dialog and plot. There are no mechanical implications for these choices however.

As for the critical path decision:

> As noted, those that side with the Order in the first game can skip the sewer entrance to Loc Muinne that you're otherwise forced through if you align yourself with Iorveth - Siegfried hooks you up

If you sided with the Scoia'tel, Igor Vivaldi will extend a line of credit to you in Vergen.